# Spreadsheet ExcelReader don't show seconds while parsing

Tags: php, excel, date, format, spreadsheet

I have an Excel file that shows dates with format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. When I'm parsing that table and print results in a web page, Spreadsheet excelReader show me a date in this format: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm`. In 99% of times that's not a problem, but in this case I need to show also seconds. I've tried to modify configuration file, but nothing changed.

Here is some information about the file:

```
* A class for reading Microsoft Excel Spreadsheets.
*
* Originally developed by Vadim Tkachenko under the name PHPExcelReader.
* (http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader)
* Based on the Java version by Andy Khan (http://www.andykhan.com).  Now
* maintained by David Sanders.  Reads only Biff 7 and Biff 8 formats.
*
* @category   Spreadsheet
* @package    Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader
* @author     Vadim Tkachenko <vt@phpapache.com>
* @copyright  1997-2005 The PHP Group
* @license    http://www.php.net/license/3_0.txt  PHP License 3.0
* @version    Release: @package_version@
* @link       http://pear.php.net/package/PackageName
* @see        OLE, Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer
*/
```

and this is class of date formats:

```
var $dateFormats = array (
        0xe => "d/m/Y H:i:s",
        0xf => "d-M-Y",
        0x10 => "d-M",
        0x11 => "M-Y",
        0x12 => "h:i a",
        0x13 => "h:i:s a",
        0x14 => "H:i",
        0x15 => "H:i:s",
        0x16 => "d/m/Y",
        0x2d => "i:s",
        0x2e => "H:i:s",
        0x2f => "i:s.S");
```